# Gatsby StaticImage src value not accepted via dot notation

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I understand that you cannot pass the source of an image to the StaticImage component as the result of a function.  However, can anyone explain to me the difference between these two examples.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image' // to take image data and render it

export default function Example() {
  const imageSrc = '../images/jonathan-adams.jpg'
  const data = {
    imageSrc: '../images/jonathan-adams.jpg',
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <StaticImage src={imageSrc} alt="alt text" /> {/* works */}
      <StaticImage src={data.imageSrc} alt="alt text" /> {/* doesn't work */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

One is a direct variable reference, and the latter is referencing the same value, but through dot notation.   Is dot notation a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is dot notation a function?

It's not a function but it's not a constant value (at least it can't be treated as constant in the scope of the `StaticImage` component) hence it can't be statically analyzed, since in the end, what it's constant is `data`, not its nested properties. That's why `imageSrc` works but `data` isn't.

> **Restrictions on using `StaticImage`**
>
> The images are loaded and processed at build time, so there are
> restrictions on how you pass props to the component. The values need
> to be statically-analyzed at build time, which means you can’t pass
> them as props from outside the component, or use the results of
> function calls, for example. You can either use static values, or
> variables within the component’s local scope.

Source: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#restrictions-on-using-staticimage

That said, you may want to use `imageSrc` approach or considering using `GatsbyImage` which accepts dynamic values (it will need a refactor and GraphQL-based approach).

Comment: Good explanation!  I guess it's the difference in the value of what's passed rather that the variable itself.